# Changing default 'posts' parameters with register_post_type_args

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, functions

everyone!

I'm having trouble trying to update WordPress core 'post' registered arguments to improve a functionality in my website. Specifically, I want to be able to have a hierarchy between my posts so I can set parents and childs for posts. Creating a custom post type to create this won't help me as all my content is based in posts.

By default, WordPress allows this only for Pages post type.

Recently, WordPress added a neat function to modify arguments from an already registered post type, called "register_post_type_args". This should work both for default and custom post types. I have come accross this code and modified to add what I need: [Change capability type of post type registered by plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215688/change-capability-type-of-post-type-registered-by-plugin)

The results are below. However, when I add this to my functions.php, somehow, I can't get this to work. My website returns a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file".

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'allow_post_hierarchy' , 10, 2 );

function allow_post_hierarchy( $args, $post_type ){

 // Do not filter any other post type
 if ( 'post' !== $post_type ) {

     // Give other post_types their original arguments
     return $args;

 }

 // Change the capability_type of the "custom-css-js" post_type
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => 'true',
    );

  // Give the custom-css-js post type it's arguments
  return $args;

}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I appreciate your input. Thanks!

Comment: WordPress doesn't seem to like having the `post` post type configured as hierarchical. When I did it, the menu link for posts changed to `Pages`. It's probably better to use categories, tags, or a custom taxonomy

Comment: Aren't you deleting all the other elements of `$args` this way (since you redefine the array)? Try `$args['hierarchical'] = 'true';` instead.

Comment: Changed it, still can't get it to work. @DaveRomsey, I also came to a code which changes my posts to Pages in the menu, however the hierarchical option still doesn't work. :(