# Changing CPT slug and taxonomy already registered in parent theme

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, child-theme, slug

I'm using Read WP (premium) with childthime. This theme have Portfolio CPT (slug: potfolio) declared in functions.php. Each project can be nested in a Department (slug: department).
If i want to see only one specific department, the URL will be something like this:

mysite.com/department/category-name.

If I want to see one specific projet, the URL will be:

mysite.com/portfolio/my-projects-name.

The question is: How can I change these two slugs? I need change:

- porfolio -> conteudo
- department -> material

I already found in code where this slug are registred, but I have no idea how to rewhrite this.

Here is the code snippet for portfolio (parent theme functions.php):

```
function create_post_type_portfolio()
    {
        $labels = array('name' => __( 'Portfolio', 'read' ),
                        'singular_name' => __( 'Portfolio Item', 'read' ),
                        'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'read' ),
                        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New', 'read' ),
                        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit', 'read' ),
                        'new_item' => __( 'New', 'read' ),
                        'all_items' => __( 'All', 'read' ),
                        'view_item' => __( 'View', 'read' ),
                        'search_items' => __( 'Search', 'read' ),
                        'not_found' =>  __( 'No Items found', 'read' ),
                        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Items found in Trash', 'read' ),
                        'parent_item_colon' => '',
                        'menu_name' => 'Portfolio' );

        $args = array(  'labels' => $labels,
                        'public' => true,
                        'exclude_from_search' => false,
                        'publicly_queryable' => true,
                        'show_ui' => true,
                        'query_var' => true,
                        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                        'capability_type' => 'post',
                        'hierarchical' => false,
                        'menu_position' => 5,
                        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions' ),
                        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => false ));

        register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );
    }
```

And the code snippet for departments (parent theme functions.php):

```
function portfolio_taxonomy()
    {
        $labels_dep = array('name' => __( 'Departments', 'read' ),
                            'singular_name' => __( 'Department', 'read' ),
                            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search', 'read' ),
                            'all_items' => __( 'All', 'read' ),
                            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Department', 'read' ),
                            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Department:', 'read' ),
                            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit', 'read' ),
                            'update_item' => __( 'Update', 'read' ),
                            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New', 'read' ),
                            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Department Name', 'read' ),
                            'menu_name' => __( 'Departments', 'read' ) );

        register_taxonomy(  'department',
                            array( 'portfolio' ),
                            array( 'hierarchical' => true,
                            'labels' => $labels_dep,
                            'show_ui' => true,
                            'public' => true,
                            'query_var' => true,
                            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'content' ) ) );


        $labels_tag = array('name' => __( 'Portfolio Tags', 'read' ),
                            'singular_name' => __( 'Portfolio Tag', 'read' ),
                            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search', 'read' ),
                            'all_items' => __( 'All', 'read' ),
                            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Portfolio Tag', 'read' ),
                            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Portfolio Tag:', 'read' ),
                            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit', 'read' ),
                            'update_item' => __( 'Update', 'read' ),
                            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New', 'read' ),
                            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Portfolio Tag Name', 'read' ),
                            'menu_name' => __( 'Portfolio Tags', 'read' ) );

        register_taxonomy(  'portfolio_tags',
                            array( 'portfolio' ),
                            array( 'hierarchical' => false,
                            'labels' => $labels_tag,
                            'show_ui' => true,
                            'public' => true,
                            'query_var' => true,
                            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio_tags' ) ) );
    }
    // end portfolio_taxonomy
```

So, how can I overrride this code without editing parent theme functions?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer for use of the `register_post_type_args` filter](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215688/change-capability-type-of-post-type-registered-by-plugin). There is also a `register_taxonomy_args` filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress 4.5 introduced the functions [unregister_post_type()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/unregister_post_type/) and [unregister_taxonomy()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/unregister_taxonomy/). You could deregister your post type respectively taxonomy and register them again with your custom settings. The post type is still named `portfolio`. You could rename it, but you would probably have to check your template files for references.

```
add_action('init', 'wpse_247924_overwrite_theme_post_types', 1000);
function wpse_247924_overwrite_theme_post_types() {

    unregister_post_type( 'portfolio' );

    $labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'Portfolio', 'read' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Portfolio Item', 'read' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'read' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New', 'read' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit', 'read' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New', 'read' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All', 'read' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View', 'read' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search', 'read' ),
        'not_found' =>  __( 'No Items found', 'read' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Items found in Trash', 'read' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Portfolio'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions' ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'conteudo',
            'with_front' => false
        )
    );

    register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );

    unregister_taxonomy( 'department' );

    $labels_dep = array(
        'name' => __( 'Departments', 'read' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Department', 'read' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search', 'read' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All', 'read' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Department', 'read' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Department:', 'read' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit', 'read' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update', 'read' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New', 'read' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Department Name', 'read' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Departments', 'read' )
    );

    register_taxonomy(
        'material',
        array( 'portfolio' ),
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => $labels_dep,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'public' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'material'
            )
        )
    );


    $labels_tag = array(
        'name' => __( 'Portfolio Tags', 'read' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Portfolio Tag', 'read' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search', 'read' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All', 'read' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Portfolio Tag', 'read' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Portfolio Tag:', 'read' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit', 'read' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update', 'read' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New', 'read' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Portfolio Tag Name', 'read' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Portfolio Tags', 'read' )
    );

    register_taxonomy(
        'portfolio_tags',
        array( 'portfolio' ),
        array(
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'labels' => $labels_tag,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'public' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'portfolio_tags'
            )
        )
    );

}
```

Comment: Thank you for you tip, but can you give me an example?
I read the codex, but I couldn't understand...

Comment: `add_action('init', 'delete_old_post_types', 1000);
function delete_post_types() {
 unregister_post_type('portfolio');
}`

This will unregister the portfolio post type, but I'm not sure about the taxonomy.

Comment: There is also a [unregister_taxonomy()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/unregister_taxonomy/) function.

Comment: Hey @luke, I've just inserted this in my child theme functions.php and got this warning in a white screen (admin). In front-end all site loads correctly, but the warning is being showed.
`Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wpse_247924_overwrite_theme_post_types' not found or invalid function name in ....`

Comment: @Luke, thank you A LOT! I've fixed some things in your code, like the add_action and other misspelling 'departement' to 'department'.
Now it's working just like I wish. Thank you man!!

Comment: Oh, yeah I missed that. I updated my answer with the fixes. Also checkout the comment by @milo as he has actually found [a more elegant solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/247911/changing-cpt-slug-and-taxonomy-already-registered-in-parent-theme/247924#comment369775_247911).